# AWS - Copying EC2 logs to S3 through cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron, aws-cli

I need to copy the logs present in `EC2` instance to `S3` bucket periodically. So I am using Amazon cli and crontab to schedule it.
In `crontab -e`, I added below lines

```
* * * * * aws --version >> /tmp/out.txt 2&>1
* * * * * aws s3 cp log_file_path  s3://bucket >> /tmp/out.txt 2&>1
```

First statement, i just used to check if aws cli works fine as I am new to this which is redirecting the aws version to a file every minute.

First command works fine but second doesn't. If I run the `aws s3 cp` command standalone, then it runs fine i.e. copy the log file to s3 bucket. But doesn't work with cron as mentioned above,

Through logs got to know that I get the below error:

```
Upload failed....An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation : Access Denied.
```

Can someone please point out how to make it work.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/614890/cant-run-aws-cli-from-cron-credentials

Comment: add logging to second line also

Comment: @DusanBajic - Updated

Comment: Do you have your aws credentials stored in `~/.aws/credentials` file?

Comment: @DusanBajic - What should be the key and values ?

Comment: If your `aws cp ..` command works when triggered manually from shell, you probably have those values somewhere (or your bucket is open to the world, but then you wouldn't get the cron error ).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have the AWS credentials setup as environment variables in your EC2 user's account. The cron job wont' have access to those environment variables, which is why you need to move them to `~/.aws/credentials`.

**However** the much better option is to [assign the permissions to the EC2 instance directly](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/iam-roles-for-ec2-instances-simplified-secure-access-to-aws-service-apis-from-ec2/) via an IAM role.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create an EC2 role with the correct permissions so that s3 actions are feasible.
Thus aws cli configuration in not needed.

Then create the script that will do the upload or any aws related actions, and at last add the cron command.

Consider creating an ec2 role as mandatory from a security and administrative perspective.